# Test if different coins are distributed evenly on both sides in R

Tags: r, statistical-significance, bernoulli-distribution

I need help to statistically test a uniform distribution of a toss of 7 independent coins.

Here is the table :

```
Coin_nb Heads Tails Nb_toss
Coin1   86    73    159
Coin2   42    63    105
Coin3   52    62    114
Coin4   53    55    108
Coin5   73    48    121
Coin6   60    77    137
Coin7   66    43    108
```

How could I test if in globally in the different coins were distributed evenly on both sides ?

Comment: How was the sampling performed. Is there a particular stopping rule? (the results can be different depending on whether or not certain margins are fixed)

Comment: The difference is explained with this example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_principle#Example . That Wikipedia also shows that there can be different approaches to testing (like Bayesian vs frequentist, among many other variations). There is no unique simple way to 'solve' this question.

Comment: Why do you need to test these 7 coins? Is this some homework from a textbook or course? The problem seems a bit weird without any context, but textbooks or course examples, often have some implicit background that you are supposed to use some method that is being used/explained in the textbook or course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `prop.test` for each row of Your data table:

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(coins_tbl)), function(i) {
  prop.test(x = as.matrix(coins_tbl[i, c(2, 3)]),
            n = coins_tbl$Nb_toss[i],
            p = 0.5)  
})
```

As a result You'll get a list of proportion confidence intervals and `p-values` like this:

````
[[1]]

    1-sample proportions test with continuity correction

data:  as.matrix(coins_tbl[i, c(2, 3)]), null probability 0.5
X-squared = 0.90566, df = 1, p-value = 0.3413
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4602640 0.6194908
sample estimates:
        p 
0.5408805 
```
````

Comment: In addition some sort of correction for multiple comparisons should be made. If you test a lot of coins, then there will always be some that have a ratio of heads and tails that is a lot different from 1:1

Comment: Thanks, I also added a p.adjust "BH" method on the pvalues